# Present simple and past together in one sentence>

Tags: tense-agreement

*" Dear sir:
I, the undersigned, hereby inform you that I had already submitted the electrical drawings for the subject-mentioned project. "
-**

The writer wants to point out that he surely has submitted the drawings sometime in the past.  The effect of the past is carried on to the present with him informing the receiver now. Is the sentence in the quotes correct ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but the context you provide doesn't require the past perfect.

There's nothing wrong with more than one tense in a sentence, especially when using a word that introduces something like a quote (eg "inform")

> I will inform you of the place I went to.

But in your context, you are speaking about a past action with consequences in the present, so present perfect is a natural choice of tense:

> I hereby inform you that I have submitted the ...

Stylistically this is over-the-top.  Unless you are following some legal template you can cut out all the "hereby inform", and don't use "subject-mentioned"  or "the undersigned".  These are all pseudo-legal expressions, and probably inappropriate.

> Dear Sir,
>
> I have submitted the electrical drawings for the {washing machine} project.

The problem with using past perfect, in this case, is that it sounds accusatory.  You seem to accuse the teacher of failing to notice that they already received the drawings.  You would only need past perfect if you are saying something like like "I had submitted my drawings before the deadline"

Comment: Why using past perfect in this case sounds as an accusation .

Comment: In combination with the highly formal (and therefore unfriendly) tone of the writing. Using the past perfect seems to imply that "I had submitted this prior to you asking it from me, and so if you don't have it that is your fault".